# my django file requirement.txt is installing while running in docker through cmd on my Window 10

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /main
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver
```

In my cmd/terminal:

```
 E:\Satya_Django_TODO_APP\todo>docker build -t my_image --rm .
[+] Building 95.5s (8/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                      0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster                 2.2s 
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim-buster@sha256:0b92aced9b0e52b16870a7c09  0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                         0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 28.89kB                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /main                                                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                                   0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                     93.0s 
------
 > [4/5] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#8 13.02 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f04029205e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/aioredis/
#8 15.23 Collecting aioredis==1.3.1
#8 25.24   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7c4c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
#8 35.75   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7c730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
#8 46.77   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7c910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
#8 58.78   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7cb20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
#8 72.80   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7cca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
#8 82.81 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/b0/64/1b1612d0a104f21f80eb4c6e1b6075f2e6aba8e228f46f229cfd3fdac859/aioredis-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0402d7ce50>: Failed to 
establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
#8 82.81
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

why my connection is not establishing ? i haven't found any exact answer till now

Comment: By mistake i have written is installing instead of is not installing.

Comment: Seems like a DNS issue. The error says it cannot resolve pipy host. Does your container have access to the web? Is a firewall active?

Comment: actually i am not able to find that how do i activate my firewall so that connection be established??

Comment: An easy way to check it with windows is to temporarily disable the firewall (control panel). Check if Docker can download the package. If it does then reactivate your firewall and add the adhoc outbound rule and you are done. Otherwise it means the problem is elsewhere. Finding how to disable the the windows firewall is heavily documented over the internet. Let us know if it solved the issue.

Comment: yes , i have done all. Container have access to the web .But still facing same issue

Comment: The error is explicit on name resolution failure which means you cannot succeed to translate the pipy host into IP and then connect it. What would prevent Docker to resolve DN while your OS can? Where your docker stack is running?